# Why an OpenDJ non-admin user can copy and remove, but cannot move an item?

Tags: permissions, ldap, opendj

### Results as I see them

The non-admin user must move an entry from the People group to the AMI group. The operation fails with the message:

```
Error while moving entry
 -  [LDAP result code 50 - insufficientAccessRights] 
The entry uid=user11,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com 
cannot be renamed due to insufficient access rights
```

If the same user copies the entry and removes it - no problems.
If the root user moves the entry - no problems.

The simple renaming is impossible for the non-admin user, with the same message.

***How can I permit the user to rename?***

### Surroundings and settings:

- OpenDJ v4.5 is used as an LDAP server
- Apache Development Studio is used as a client

The server has three ou:

- `ou=Administrators,dc=example,dc=com` - where the only non-admin user lives
- `ou=AMI,dc=example,dc=com` - AMI group
- `ou=People,dc=example,dc=com` - People group

The non-admin user is:

```
uid=idm,ou=Administrators,dc=example,dc=com
```

By the client I imported the following permission into the dc=example,dc=com root:

```
aci: (target="ldap:///dc=example,dc=com")(targetattr="*||+")(version 3.0; acl "IDM Access"; allow (all,proxy,import,export) userdn="ldap:///uid=idm,ou=Administrators,dc=example,dc=com";)
```

You can notice that all possible sorts of `targetattr` and `allow` are covered, according to the [Administration Guide](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/3/admin-guide/#about-acis).

Option "update existing entries" was checked while importing. The import shows no errors.

I thought that maybe, I should set for the user not permissions, but privileges. Alas, in [the list of privileges](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/3/admin-guide/#about-privileges) I saw no one that looked as (allow to rename)

Answer (score -1):

As documented (https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/3.5/admin-guide/#aci-permissions), to move an entry you need the import and export permissions in Aci. These permissions are not included in “all”.

Comment: The export and import are included apart from "all", look once again.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the source of the problem. Either OpenDJ or Apache dev. studio with it accept aci settings only simultaneously with the setting of the appropriate of the group(ou). `aci` cannot be attached to an already existing group by a separate ldif import.

Comment: Ldif import is a data initialization process. Subsequent changes such as adding aci or any data must be done using LDAP operations. Directories services have worked this way for decades.